# How to config org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration in spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa,and i want to register a custom BasicType in Hibernate.

According to the [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/basic_types.html),i need org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration object to register.

```
configuration.registerTypeContributor( (typeContributions, serviceRegistry) -> {
    typeContributions.contributeType( BitSetType.INSTANCE );
} );
```

But in spring-boot I don't know how to get org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-a-custom-basic-type-using-hibernate-usertype/. take a look to that